# Bigcommerce custom private apps development storefront content injection blueprint and stencil

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce, bigcommerce

I am trying to create a custom private app for my client, this app will interact in the storefront.

eg. I need to put a button on storefront product page and when that button click popup will show and the content of popup will come from my private app website.

The problem in broad is I cannot find a documentation wherein it will discuss all for eg. how to support blueprint and stencil for UI or content that I'll inject on the storefront.

By the way, I already successfully setup the `hello-world-app-php-silex`.

The specific problem that I am facing now is I am able to inject the content( button and bootstrap modal ) for blueprint framework, however, I cannot make it works on the stencil.

Any suggestion or tutorial link?

Thanks!

Comment: Why down vote? any issue with my question?

Comment: Do I need to be specific more or whatever?

Comment: Could you share relevant sections of your code, or any errors you're getting with Stencil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigCommerce recently released the ability to programmatically inject scrpts on Stencil using the Script API here is the API documentation and guidelines on how to approach the blueprint vs stencil
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/scripts.html

Also, you can find some examples on injecting snippets by editing theme files here:
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/checkout-injection#footer however, using the API is highly recommended. That way the theme can be kept on the upgrade path.

I hope that helps.